# Store a closure with generic type

Tags: ios, swift

I am writing tests for a structure that has a `func` with a closure whom in turn has a child parameter of `Result<ModelProtocol>`. 
However, when I am writing the mock for my struct it refuses to store the closure thinking that `<T> != <ModelProtocol>`. In turn this is correct, since this is a generic type.

The error I am getting now is:

```
Playground execution failed:

error: Test.playground:51:49: error: cannot assign value of type '(Result<T>) -> Void' to type '((Result<ModelProtocol>) -> Void)?'
            self.doSomethingCompletionHandler = completionHandler
                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Which is the problem because `<T>` actually is of type `T: ModelProtocol`.
How can I store the closure (completionHandler) so I can call it at a later point to run the closure manually (by the test).

This is an example of what my problem in a playground:

```
public enum Result<Value> {

    case success(Value)
    case failure(Error)

    public var value: Value? {
        switch self {
        case .success(let value):
            return value
        case .failure:
            return nil
        }
    }

    public var error: Error? {
        switch self {
        case .success:
            return nil
        case .failure(let error):
            return error
        }
    }
}

protocol ModelProtocol {
    init(aString: String)
}

protocol AnImportantProtocol {
    func doSomething<T: ModelProtocol>(firstParameter: String, completionHandler: @escaping((Result<T>)->Void))
}

enum StructureError : Error {
    case defaultError
}

struct StructureOne : AnImportantProtocol {

    func doSomething<T: ModelProtocol>(firstParameter: String, completionHandler: @escaping ((Result<T>) -> Void)) {
        debugPrint("Doing something")

        if let model = ExampleModel(aString: "Test") as? T {
            completionHandler(.success(model))
        } else {
            completionHandler(.failure(StructureError.defaultError))
        }
    }
}

class StructureOneMock : AnImportantProtocol {

    var doSomethingInvokeCount: Int = 0
    var doSomethingCompletionHandler: ((Result<ModelProtocol>)->Void)? = nil

    func doSomething<T: ModelProtocol>(firstParameter: String, completionHandler: @escaping ((Result<T>) -> Void)) {
        self.doSomethingInvokeCount += 1
        self.doSomethingCompletionHandler = completionHandler
    }

    func callCompletionHandler(result: Result<ModelProtocol>) {
        if let doSomethingCompletionHandler = self.doSomethingCompletionHandler {
            doSomethingCompletionHandler(result)
        }
    }
}

struct ExampleModel {
    let someString: String
}

extension ExampleModel : ModelProtocol {
    init(aString: String) {
        self.someString = aString
    }
}
```

Comment: How you are going to handle success part for `StructureOne` ?

Comment: with your code when i try             `completionHandler(Result.success(ModelProtocol.init(aString: firstParameter)))` in `StructOne` not working for me

Comment: Updated the example code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have a contravariance error that isn't obvious because the variance is happening in the generic parameter.

Consider the following code:

```
class Cat {}
class Kitten: Cat {}
class Cougar: Cat {}

protocol CatDayCareProtocol {
    func setRaiseFunction(raiseFunction: @escaping (Cat) -> Cougar)
}

class CatDayCare: CatDayCareProtocol {
    func setRaiseFunction(raiseFunction: @escaping (Cat) -> Cougar) {
        self.raiseFunction = raiseFunction
    }
    private var raiseFunction: ((Cat) -> Cougar)? = nil

    func callCougerRaiseFunction() -> Cougar? {
        let cougar = Cougar()
        return raiseFunction?(cougar)
    }
}

let catDayCare = CatDayCare()

catDayCare.setRaiseFunction(raiseFunction: { kitty: Kitten in
    return Cougar()
})
```

In this example, swift throws the following error:

```
error: Contravariance.playground:23:51: error: expected expression
catDayCare.setRaiseFunction(raiseFunction: { kitty: Kitten in
```

This seems unintuitive as a kitten is a Cat, so wouldn't this be fine? Let's consider what happens if you tried to do the callCougerRaiseFunction(). It instantiates a cougar, which is a cat, and calls its raise function, which expects a cat so this is legal. However, if you pass a function expecting a kitten as a parameter, suddenly you are passing a cougar to a function that wants a kitten and it is sad.

Now for your example, you have

```
func doSomething<T: ModelProtocol>(firstParameter: String, completionHandler: @escaping ((Result<T>) -> Void)) {
    self.doSomethingInvokeCount += 1
    self.doSomethingCompletionHandler = completionHandler
}
```

In this example, T is strictly just as or more specific than a ModelProtocol (as it could be any protocol that inherits from ModelProtocol), which I believe makes `Result<T>` as a function parameter contravariant with the data type `Result<ModelProtocol>`. It is just that the compiler isn't quite smart enough to know it is contravariance, but it does know the conversion isn't legal.

As for actually solving the problem, is it really necessary to use a generic? Why can't you just use:

```
protocol AnImportantProtocol {
    func doSomething(firstParameter: String, completionHandler: @escaping((Result<ModelProtocol>)->Void))
}
```

Comment: I might just a well do without the genericType as you suggested. I like your explanation very much, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are probably better off using an associatedType constraint in this case, for example:

```
protocol AnImportantProtocol {
    associatedtype MyType: ModelProtocol
    func doSomething(firstParameter: String, completionHandler ((Result<MyType>)->Void)?)
}
```

Then you typealias in the implementations:

```
class StructureOneMock<T: ModelProtocol> : AnImportantProtocol {

typealias MyType = T

var doSomethingInvokeCount: Int = 0
var doSomethingCompletionHandler: ((Result<MyType>)->Void)? = nil

func doSomething(firstParameter: String, completionHandler: ((Result<MyType>) -> Void)?) {
    self.doSomethingInvokeCount += 1
    self.doSomethingCompletionHandler = completionHandler
}

func callCompletionHandler(result: Result<MyType>) {
    if let doSomethingCompletionHandler = self.doSomethingCompletionHandler {
        doSomethingCompletionHandler(result)
    }
}
}
```

You could skip the generic T in the implementations and specify a concrete type there.